# My site language is undetected?

Tags: 7, theming, i18n-l10n

My D7 site uses Hebrew as it's default language, and though, an application such as SEOquake told me that the language is undetected. now, that's not an SEO question and it has really nothing to do with SEOquake, i just use it as an example for the given situation of an external device not detecting the language.

I have been told to add the following input, but i have no clue how to do it on Drupal, not even at the TPL files (if it's even a starting point), the input:

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL">
```

How could i apply this to all pages of the site?

Thank you very much.

Comment: While declaring the language is in principle a good thing to do, doing it please SEOquake is pointless. SEOquake looks like snake oil: it just checks for the presence of a `lang` attribute, without even checking the syntax of its value, so it congratulated me for `lang=???` (literally). And there is no evidence of any search engine actually looking at such attributes. Google, for one, explicitly says they don’t.

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my html.tpl.php file:

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>"
    version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"
>
```

where $language is a global object, it prints, in my case:

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xml:lang="en"
    version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="ltr"
>
```

[Check out the variables available to you in html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21html.tpl.php/7).

Make sure to clear your cache after you change the template.

**EDIT**: Full contents of html.tpl.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"
    <?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>
    <head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
        <?php print $head; ?>
        <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
        <?php print $styles; ?>
        <?php print $scripts; ?>
    </head>
    <body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
        <?php print $page_top; ?>
        <?php print $page; ?>
        <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that's for the XHTML, not HTML, doctype. If OP's theme is HTML5, it'll need `dir` and `lang`, without the `xml:` prefix

Comment: It seems i don't have such a file at all. I use Bartik theme.

Comment: You can create an html.tpl.php file in your template's template folder

Comment: And just put this input in it?

(Sorry for asking, I just really don't want to make some mess).

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full contents